# Does $\left\vert\mathrm{sech}^2(x)\mathrm{tanh}(x)\mathrm{tanh}\left(\dfrac{x}{10a}\right)\right\vert\leq\dfrac{10}{a^2}$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

Playing a little bit with wolfram I "found" an interesting (?) inequailty
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \qquad \left\vert\mathrm{sech}^2(x)\mathrm{tanh}(x)\mathrm{tanh}\left(\dfrac{x}{10a}\right)\right\vert\leq\dfrac{10}{a^2},
$$
for all parameters $a\gg 1$. Here, when I say that I "found" this inequality, I mean that I check it for several huge values of $a$, so I was wondering if it actually holds for all $a$ sufficiently large, let's say, $a>10$. What confuses me is that, at first order, the left-hand should behave as $\tfrac{1}{a}x^2$, so it doesn't looks that easy to obtain a $a^{-2}$ on the right-hand side. Does anyone knows how to prove something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false.

For $a\ge 313$ let's say, $a=400$ we have that LHS
$$\tanh \left(\frac{x}{4000}\right) \tanh (x) \text{sech}^2(x)$$
has a max $0.00008$ at $x=1.0095$, larger than RHS value $\frac{10}{400^2}=0.0000625$